# How to set a recurring Cron job with an initial starting time?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

How do I set up a Cron job to start at 6:00 AM (GMT +0) and run every six hours indefinitely? (6:00, 12:00, 18:00, 24:00)

I have tried this:

```
cron:
- description: Scrape every 6 hours
  url: /api/v1.0/generator
  schedule: every 6 hours synchronized
```

I am not sure how to set the starting time for that job.

I see in the local environment (http://localhost:8000/cron) the following:

```
every 6 hours synchronized
In production, this would run at these times:
2015-02-03 00:00:00Z 0:09:46.785390 from now
2015-02-03 06:00:00Z 6:09:46.785390 from now
2015-02-03 12:00:00Z 12:09:46.785390 from now
```

This seems to start at 12 AM, 6 AM, 12 PM and then it stops there? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: the local dev't server doesn't run cron jobs, it just shows you the next few times the job *would* run in production.  The production arrangement wouldn't stop after those first few jobs, there are potentially infinite following times, but the display can't be infinite, so it just shows a few.  So, in your shoes, I wouldn't worry!

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to set a starting time + timezone for that?

Comment: Done, and made it an answer as you previously suggested, with my best idea on how to set starting times (**nearly** where you want them:-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local dev't server doesn't run cron jobs, it just shows you the next few times the job would run in production.

The production arrangement wouldn't stop after those first few jobs, there are potentially infinite following times, but the display can't be infinite, so it just shows a few.

So, in your shoes, I wouldn't worry!

WRT how to set the starting time: in the general syntax, given as

```
every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
```

the specific use

```
every 6 hours from 5:58 to 23:59
```

should work - yes it would run each job a minute or two earlier than you'd prefer but I'm striving to work around the "23:59 is the last time in the day" constraint.